# Fourier series, find $a_n$ of $\sin x$, $x \in [0,\pi]$

Tags: fourier-series

Fourier series, find $a_n$ of $\sin x$, $x \in [0,\pi]$

I tried to solve it myself, and then I got stucked with $\cos(\pi+\pi n)$ there, I uploaded an image of the solution, I didn't understand the part in red.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lemma:  For any integer $k$, $\cos k\pi = (-1)^k$.

Nonproof:  This isn't a formal proof but from the below chart we can clearly see a pattern forming.

\begin{array}{c|c}
  k & \cos k\pi\\
  \hline
  0 & \cos 0 = 1 = (-1)^0\\
  1 & \cos \pi = -1 = (-1)^1\\
  2 & \cos 2\pi = 1 = (-1)^2\\
  3 & \cos 3\pi = -1 = (-1)^3\\
  4 & \cos 4\pi = 1 = (-1)^4
\end{array}
And so on.  And this pattern holds for $k < 0$ as well.

Using this, you can say $\cos(n+1)\pi = (-1)^{n+1}$, etc.  I haven't worked it out completely but I think it may also be beneficial to note that $(-1)^{n+1} = (-1)^{n-1}$ because $n+1$ and $n-1$ have the same parity.

Let me know if you require further guidance.